# Parse nested JSON Response Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I know there are several threads on this subject but I've looked through over 30 threads without success. 
I have managed to parse a JSON response so it looks like this:

```
   {
    "1": {
       "id": "1",
       "name": "Fruit",
       .
       .
       .
       "entities": {
          "1": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "blue bird",
       .
       .
       .
       "status": "1"
    },
   "2": {
```

using this code

```
    let json = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(json);
```

Now I want to access the "id", "name" etc. AND the "id" and "name" for the "entities" tag.
So far I have tried:

```
    console.log(json[0]);
    console.log(json.id);
```

which both returns undefined

I have also tried

```
    console.log(json[0].id);
```

which gives an error

Any ideas?

Comment: looks like your first key is `json["1"]`

Comment: LOL easy fix haha thanks!

Comment: Sure, I'll add as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance, your first key is `1`, so you can access it with `json[1]`.

```js
const json = {
  "1": {
    "id": "1",  
    "name": "Fruit"
  },
  "2": {
    "id": "2",  
    "name": "Veggies"
  }
};

console.log(json[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this json, you can reach the id by

```
json.1.id
```

But I think that first of all your json is not correctly written, you should have something like

```
{ 
"elements": [
    { "id" : 1, "name" : "fruit" },
    { "id" : 2, "name" : "vegetable" }
]
}
```

like that, json.elements is a collection/array, and you can loop, count, or any other things you will not be able to do because your json looks like a super heavy list of different properties ( he doesn't know that json.1 and json.2 are the same type of objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
const jsonData = JSON.parse(body);

for (const i in jsonData) {
  for (const j in jsonData[i]) {
    console.log('${i}: ${jsonData[i][j]}');
  }
}
```